# Python Tkinter replacing the label and command of a button by clicking another button

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm writing a scientific calculator with 2nd button. What is the function for second button so  for example it changes sin to sin^-1, plus changing the sin button command; and if you click the 2nd button again, it changes sin^-1 back to sin

Comment: Basically, how to replace the button back an forth by clicking the second button

Comment: Please paste your code so we can look at it and try to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split my calculator up into section using different frames (one to show the calculations , one with buttons which won't have 2 functions and lastly the buttons which have 2 functions).
The reason I would split it up is because I would use destroying objects and making the new ones this splitting up means you can destroy the wanted frame rather than specific buttons (would require less code). Also for this I would have 3 create GUI defs. one would be the buttons with one function and the bit showing the calculations. one be the buttons which have 2 functions (their first function) and lastly the buttons which have 2 functions (their second functions). To decide between which GUI gen def to use have an if statement with global variable which gets changed each time 2nd function button called and that decides which def to use.

If it was just commands you wanted changing instead of both labels and commands I would have a variable which is etheir 1 or 2(change when 2nd button clicked) then in your definitions (ones which your buttons call) have an if statement to decide between to do normal action (e.g cos) or 2nd action (e.g cos-1).

Here is code below that uses what i have described in the first paragraph:

```
from tkinter import *

class Calc(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.modefunction = 1
        """ Initialize the frame. """
        super(Calc,self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()

        self.calculations_frm = Frame(self, width=100, height=30)#bg = "red"
        self.calculations_frm.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan=2)

        self.buttons_frm = Frame(self, width= 50, height=30,)#bg = "green")
        self.buttons_frm.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        self.buttons_2_functions_1_frm = Frame(self, width=50, height=30)#bg = "blue")
        self.buttons_2_functions_1_frm.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.create_GUI()

    def create_show_calculations(self):
        self.calculation_lbl = Label(self.calculations_frm, text = "will show caluclations here").pack()

    def create_buttons(self):
        #mc stands for mode change
        self.mode_change_btn = Button(self.buttons_frm, text = "mc", command = self.mode_change, height = 1, width = 5)
        self.mode_change_btn.grid(row = 0,column = 0)

        self.plus_btn = Button(self.buttons_frm, text = "plus", height = 1, width = 5)
        self.plus_btn.grid(row = 1,column = 0)

    def create_GUI(self):
        self.create_show_calculations()
        self.create_buttons()
        self.create_1_function_gui()


    def create_1_function_gui(self):
        self.tan_btn = Button(self.buttons_2_functions_1_frm, text = "tan", height = 1, width = 5)
        self.tan_btn.grid(row = 0,column = 0)

        self.san_btn = Button(self.buttons_2_functions_1_frm, text = "san", height = 1, width = 5)
        self.san_btn.grid(row = 0,column = 1)

        self.coz_btn = Button(self.buttons_2_functions_1_frm, text = "coz", height = 1, width = 5)
        self.coz_btn.grid(row = 1,column = 0)

    def create_2_function_gui(self):
        self.buttons_2_functions_2_frm = Frame(self, width=50, height=30)#bg = "blue")
        self.buttons_2_functions_2_frm.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        self.inverse_tan_btn = Button(self.buttons_2_functions_2_frm, text = "tan-1", height = 1, width = 5)
        self.inverse_tan_btn.grid(row = 0,column = 0)

        self.inverse_san_btn = Button(self.buttons_2_functions_2_frm, text = "san-1", height = 1, width = 5)
        self.inverse_san_btn.grid(row = 0,column = 1)

        self.inverse_coz_btn = Button(self.buttons_2_functions_2_frm, text = "coz-1", height = 1, width = 5)
        self.inverse_coz_btn.grid(row = 1,column = 0)

    def mode_change(self):
        if self.modefunction == 1:
            self.buttons_2_functions_1_frm.destroy()
            self.modefunction = 2
            self.buttons_2_functions_2_frm = Frame(self, width=50, height=30)#bg = "blue")
            self.buttons_2_functions_2_frm.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
            self.create_2_function_gui()
        else:
            self.buttons_2_functions_2_frm.destroy()
            self.modefunction =  1
            self.buttons_2_functions_1_frm = Frame(self, width=50, height=30)#bg = "blue")
            self.buttons_2_functions_1_frm.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
            self.create_1_function_gui()

root = Tk()
root.title("booking system")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.configure(bg="white")
app = Calc(root)

root.mainloop()
```